# Subsonic 3.0 and DB2 support?

Tags: .net, subsonic, subsonic3

It doesn't appear so from the online docs, but I wanted to ask the question here anyway.

Will Subsonic 3.0 support DB2? Specifically, I'm working on an enterprise app that needs to connect to DB2 on MVS.

Answer (score 2):

It could support DB2, but someone would need to contribute the provider for it. I would [discuss it on the mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/subsonicproject).

Answer (score 0):

SubSonic offers the following providers:

- MySqlDataProvider
- OracleDataProvider
- SqlCEProvider
- SqlDataProvider
- SQLiteDataProvider

But, as you can see, a DB2 provider hasn't been developed/contributed yet.